# Can I use different libs on the browser/node.js, without having to edit package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

The [xhr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xhr) library provides a way to do requests on both browser and node.js under the same API. For that, you must require another library, [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), and edit your `package.json` to tell browserify to replace `request` by `xhr`, which is much lighter and thus more appropriate than minifying the whole `request` lib. I wonder if there is a way to achieve the same effect without editing `package.json`. Something like:

```
#if browserify
    const req = require("xhr")
#else
    const req = require("request")
```

Comment: just bumped into this [browserify-conditionally](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-conditionalify) module.. maybe it could be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to something like this:

```
let req;
if (process.browser) {
    req = require("xhr");
} else {
    const nodeRequire = require;
    req = nodeRequire("request");
}
```

Note that `nodeRequire` is neccessary to prevent Browserify from bundling `request`.